# How do I use ZALO with the Appropriate Size with VMware-Player's display screen

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-player, instant-messaging

I use ZALO instant messenger on my VM-ware Workstation 12 Player, I have used the large size for the display screen of the VM-ware Player which is 3840 x 2160. But after I installed ZALO, ZALO has a big screen (not appropriate with VM-ware Player), so that I cannot see all the display of the ZALO.

I run ZALO on Windows 7 over VM-ware player (my guest OS is Windows OS) and my host OS is Windows 7 too.

Anybody here that can help me please to do adjustment of the ZALO's size, how do I do it?
Any suggestion would be appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the Zalo app from Vietnam? If yes then it doesn't support hidpi the last time I checked and always appear tiny. Try disabling the scaling option in compatibility mode in the exe file's properties. And please describe your problem more clearly and include screenshot if available

Comment: Hi @LưuVĩnhPhúc thanks a lot for prompt response. Yes I mean ZALO app from Vietnam. I have tried to do your suggestion by disable display scaling on high DPI setting at Compatibility part of the ZALO app, unfortunately it cannot work anymore. I still cannot use ZALO with appropriate size with my VMware workstation player's screen.

Comment: I haven't try vmware on hidpi settings so I don't know how it handles hidpi but probably your dpi value is set to 200% so vmware is already twice as large, then in the virtual machine it's set again to 200% and making things 4 times bigger. Anyway you can use the zalo web in the mean time. The features are the same as the PC version